# localhost redirecting to HTTPS even after Docker container is removed

Tags: proxy, docker, nginx

I am running Fedora 32 and after using and configuring a Docker image with Nginx with an HTTPS proxy pass and deleting all the running containers, I'm continue get a redirect of `http://localhost` to `https://localhost`.

I've searched on the web and found that can be cache, not in my case.

I removed and reinstalled the Podman (I'm using Podman instead the Docker CLI because there's a bug with cgroups on Docker Compose) without building the images and seeing any running containers, only one that cannot be removed. There's no built image, so, there's no container running the Nginx.

I am not using [HTTPS Everywhere](http://https%20everywhere%20chrome). On Chromium I'm getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, but it doesn’t show the HTTPS. On Firefox I get an “unable to connect” error.

What may be causing this issue and how to solve?

Comment: How are you determining the HTTPS redirect for `localhost`? Via a web browser or the command line? What is your host OS? I would recommend checking the output of `curl -ILk localhost` to confirm this is a networking issue and not a browser issue. That Curl command will show you the chain of headers connected to a web request to `localhost`. If this were a browser issue, the final destination should be a 200 response with the plain HTTP in place. If it is a networking issue the final destination will be HTTPS. Please post that output — as well as the OS version you are on — to your question.

Comment: ```curl: Warning: error trying read config from the 'localhost' file

curl: no URL specified!``` of curl

Using fedora 32.

Comment: That’s odd. Is there a `localhost` file in your directory? Try this: `curl -ILk http://localhost`

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Comment: What browser do you use to test this stuff out? Can you use another browser of some kind and see how it reacts?

Comment: On chromium I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, but doest' show the https. On fireforx I get Unable to connect error.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your browser is caching the redirect.

If you used a 302 redirect it will eventually expire. If you used a 301 redirect then that's permanent until you wipe the browser cache.

Either way, to solve it now, remove the cache and retry. Or in developer tools, check the box to not use the cache (in Firefox that's under the network tab, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>).

Comment: On firefox has no data about localhost.

Comment: @lukaswilkeer data != cache

Comment: the network tab shows that calls to https.

Comment: @lukaswilkeer Do you by any chance have [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere) installed? What happens when you use another web browser?

Comment: No, (to HTTPS Everywhere). On chromium I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, but doest' show the https. On fireforx I get Unable to connect error.